# Event hub azure functions bulk insert produces violation of primary key

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, azure-functions, efcore.bulkextensions

I have an EventHub-triggered Azure Functions to receive many datasets and insert them to the SQL Server database. To avoid duplication, reduce SQL concurrent connection and fast the process I am using [SqlBulk](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions) insert.

I have this code:

```
public class StaffEntrance
{
    public string StaffId { get; set; }
    public long UnixDate { get; set; }
    public string Gate { get; set; }
    ... other properties
}
```

Both `StaffId` and `UnixDate` are primary keys.

The following methods are

```
[Function("sync")]
public async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("sync", Connection = "constevthub", ConsumerGroup = "syncgroup")] string[] input)
{
    if (input == null || input.Length == 0) return;
    try
    {
        ...desirializations and validations
        var staff = staffEntrances.DistinctBy(x => new { x.StaffId, x.UnixDate }).ToList();
        await Insert(staff);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ..Log to table
    }
}

async Task<List<StaffEntrance>> Insert(List<StaffEntrance> staff)
{
    BulkConfig bulkConfig = new()
    {
        WithHoldlock = false,
        UseOptionLoopJoin = false
    };
    await context.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(staff, bulkConfig); 
    await context.BulkSaveChangesAsync();
    return staff;
}
```

This functions is triggered every one or two minutes and contains hundred or thousand of records. Before inserting these records I distinct the values by primary keys to avoid duplication. Unfortunately, this duplication still happens occasionally. In one day it can be 50 to 90 errors indicating duplicate values

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_StaffEntrance'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.StaffEntrance'. The duplicate key value is (1697793420, 204403454).  The statement has been terminated

Comment: Have you read through the [BulkExtensions documentation](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions) yet? This seems relevant, _If we want Insert only new and skip existing ones in Db (Insert_if_not_Exist) then use BulkInsertOrUpdate with config `PropertiesToIncludeOnUpdate = new List<string> { "" }`_